# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH In camel Jetty websockets

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

I bought ssl certificate and i got .cert file which i imported in jks file using keytool

I configure camel like this

```
<camel:sslContextParameters
      id="sslContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers
        keyPassword="asdf123456">
      <camel:keyStore
          resource="keystore12.jks"
          password="Removed"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
      <camel:keyStore
          resource="keystore12.jks"
          password="Removd"/>
    </camel:trustManagers>
   <camel:secureSocketProtocols>
     <camel:secureSocketProtocol>TLSv1.2</camel:secureSocketProtocol>
   </camel:secureSocketProtocols>
```

and i used this like :-

```
<route id="marketDataMessage">
            <from uri="direct:uimessages" />
            <to uri="websocket://0.0.0.0:8443/ws/mdata?sendToAll=true&amp;sslContextParameters=#sslContextParameters" />
        </route>
```

but when i am trying to open websocket i am getting this.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

```
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This worked finally . it didn't have private key so it was showing this error. I loaded private key using this https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked finally . it didn't have private key so it was showing this error. I loaded private key using this

```
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key
```

and it worked